# QRコードからのインストールについて

Tags: monaca

MonacaでiOS build(AdHoc)した際に発行されるQRコードですが、一定の時間が経過しQRコードを読み取りインストールをしようとした場合に次のメッセージが表示されますが　"The package has already been expired. Please make build again"　一体どの程度の時間が経つとQRコードは無効になるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

一定時間経過でMonacaのサーバよりアプリのパッケージは削除されてしまいます。
再度ビルドすることによりインストールできますが、前のURLは無効になります。
自身で配布したい場合は
SSLでサーバ証明書を発行した上でサーバでインストールページを作るのが良いでしょう。
また、ipaファイルを保存して置いて、iTunesでインストールしてもらうのも1つの手です。